# expression block in xcos gives "answer given for scilab expression is wrong" error

Tags: scilab, xcos

I'm trying to use the xcos/scicos expressionless block:

> [image]

with this scilab/scicoslab expression:

```
sign(u2 – u1) * (2 * ((Fm + M) * abs(u2 – u1) + k * (u2^2 – u1^2) / 2) / m)^0.5
```

where all the variables above has already been defined in the context. But it keeps giving me random errors:

> [image]
>
> answer given for scilab expression is incorrect...

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the probelm and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I checked [the expression block's description](http://www.scicos.org/HELP/eng/scicos/EXPRESSION.htm) and it seems it does not support power or sqrt! The only supported functions are:

> sin, cos, tan, exp, log, sinh, cosh, tanh, int, round, ceil, floor, sign, abs, max, min, asin, acos, atan, asinh, acosh, atanh, atan2, log10.

There is the [Scilab function block](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/scifunc_block_m.html) which is much more handy:

> [image]

There you can call user-defined Scilab functions. I have explained the procedure [here in details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816664/4999991).