# Include a Scilab function/script as a block in xcos/scicos

Tags: scilab, xcos

As the title says I want to include a block where I can run a scilab expression/function/script given certain inputs. I can see xcos/scicos can include C, Fortran and Modelica. There is a Expression block:

> [image]

but [the functions](http://www.scicos.org/HELP/eng/scicos/EXPRESSION.htm) are pretty limited:

> sin, cos, tan, exp, log, sinh, cosh, tanh, int, round, ceil, floor, sign, abs, max, min, asin, acos, atan, asinh, acosh, atanh, atan2, log10.

for example if I want to solve a second order equation of `ax^2+bx+c=d` there are no `sqrt` or `power`/`^` operators/functions! Ideally I want to just run a Scilab script/function where I can have complete freedom. I would appreciate if you could help me know if there is such a block in either xcos or scicos.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Rupak and Anuradha from Spoken-Tutorial IIT Bombay](https://spoken-tutorial.org/watch/Scilab/Calling+User+Defined+Functions+in+XCOS/English/) I found the solution. Create a Scilab function as:

```
function [y1, y2, ...] = myFunction(u1, u2, ...)
    // some commands ...
    yi = // return value;
endfunction
```

and save it as `myFunction.sci` in your preferred location.

Then execute the function once (in editor) or run the command:

```
exec('path\to\myFunction.sci', -1)
```

in the console so it will be in the Scilab memory.

Then use the [Scilab function block](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/scifunc_block_m.html) in your block diagram:

> [image]

open the `Scilab Multiple Values Request` by double clocking on the block, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or right click and select `Block Parameters ...`:

> [image]

Here you can specify the size of input and output matrices. For example `[1,1;2,3]` refers to two matrices with `1×1` and `2×3` sizes. By selecting `OK` the `Scilab Input Value Request` will open:

> [image]

here you can put the function you just defined `y=myFunction(u);` or use any other Scilab built in syntax. Now simply select `OK` four times till the settings are finished.

For a more elaborate example you may follow [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgBD52cRNJk).