# Scilab xcos: run a script or define a function in Simulation -> Set Context

Tags: scilab, xcos

I have my own function which I want to use via [scifunc_block_m](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/scifunc_block_m.html) block. The function is defined in an .sci file, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816664/). Running the script from the scilab console before starting the simulation works fine. However, if I call `exec()` of this very .sci under xcos Simulation -> Set Context instead, the function seem to remain unknown in xcos. Am I missing something about the context setting?

[image: xcos Set Context]

It began with a function typed into scifunc_block_m or expression block. However,

- I didn't want to make the block big and was unable to use `..` to split the function definition over multiple lines to prevent the text spilling over the block boundaries.
- The function will be used several times, I wanted a single definition vs copy&paste.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the Set Context part:
   I guess that you must specify the absolute path of fader_func.sci, either directly in the set Context box, or through a variable defined in the console:

```scilab
--> fader_PATH = "C:\the\path\fader_func.sci"
// Then in the Context box;
exec(fader_PATH,-1);
```

Or directly in the Context box (far less portable solution):

```scilab
exec("C:\the\path\fader_func.sci", -1);
```

2. about scifunc_block_m input
   Continuation dots are unlikely supported. Instead, have you tried to explicitly split any long instruction in several shorter ones?

```scilab
tmp = tanh((u3-u1+u2/2)/0.25/abs(u2))
y1 = 0.5 + sign(u2)*tmp/2
```